# How to speed up MongoDB count() Queries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My collection is described as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5474af69d4b28042fb63b856"), "name" : "XXXX", "action" : "accept", "source" : "127.0.0.1", "srcport" : "80", "destination" : "192.168.0.13", "dstport" : "53213", "service" : "443", "service_id" : "https", "unixtime" : NumberLong("1412774569000"), "segment" : "MySegment", "direction" : "INCOMING", "location" : "US" }
```

I currently have ~5.5mio entries in my collection and the base query always is:

```
collection.count({"action":"2_different_action_types", "direction":"3_different_directions", "unixtime": {"$gte": 1412774000000, "$lte": 1412774900000}})
```

Action, direction and unixtime always exist in my query but their value is dynamic. Optional (also dynamic values) parameters are:

- location
- segment
- service_id

For example:

```
collection.count({"action":"2_different_action_types", "direction":"3_different_directions", "location":"US","segment":"mySegment", "unixtime": {"$gte": 1412774000000, "$lte": 1412774900000}})
collection.count({"action":"2_different_action_types", "direction":"3_different_directions", "service_id":"https", "unixtime": {"$gte": 1412774000000, "$lte": 1412774500000}})
```

I created the following indexes:

```
db.collection.createIndex( {unixtime: 1, action: 1, direction: 1 })
db.collection.createIndex( {unixtime: 1, action: 1, direction: 1 , location:1})
db.collection.createIndex( {unixtime: 1, action: 1, direction: 1 , service_id:1})
db.collection.createIndex( {unixtime: 1, action: 1, direction: 1 , segment:1})
db.collection.createIndex( {unixtime: 1, action: 1, direction: 1 , location:1, service_id: 1})
db.collection.createIndex( {unixtime: 1, action: 1, direction: 1 , location:1, segment: 1})
```

My query without the index took ~8sec, the query with an index ~6sec, which is still kinda slow.

How can I speed up the whole thing? Note, that at the moment I'm just counting the findings, not really looking for a specific entry.

Additional Info:

I'm currently trying to optimize those queries directly in the mongoshell but in the end, I'm querying via NodeJS (don't know if this is relevant for the solution).

Comment: Try with map-reduce functionality of mongo

Answer (score 2):

The indexes don't seem to make much sense this way. Not-equals-queries like `$gte` and `$lte` should be at the end - not only in the query, but also in the index. Putting unixtime at position 1 in the index is generally a bad idea (unless you need the set of distinct actions within a single second and the number of actions in a single second is so large that they need indexing, which is unlikely).

Try to reverse the indexes and make sure the order of the index matches the order in the query.

If `location`, `segment` and `service_id` have low selectivity, try without an index on these fields first. More indexes cost more RAM and slow insertion and update time, but with low selectivity, the gain in queries is sometimes negligible. In the query, it might make sense to put the optional fields last, at the end of all the other operations - if the candidate set is small enough after the required criteria and the `unixtime` interval, a collection scan of the remaining items shouldn't hurt performance too badly. If they do and the selectivity is high, move them further forward.

Comment: Dunno, it was not me. I tried to change the order so i got ~3.5sec for my queries but I don't know if that's a good result or not.

Comment: Can you post the output of `.explain()` (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) in your question? That will help to analyze what's going on.

Comment: I made a screenshot for a better view (this query took 2s which is quite good but as I said, I don't have any experience regarding mongo queries so I can't tell if that's a good value or not): http://www11.pic-upload.de/04.12.14/41vu8sobwp9.png

Comment: Hm, since it uses a `BTreeCursor` and `nScanned` is almost equal to `n`, I'd say the index is used efficiently. The problem is that `count()` is still traversing 1M objects, which takes time. It might be worthwhile to consider caching the results of certain criteria sets, but that might not be feasible from a requirements perspective. The last way to improve the query is to ensure it's covered by the index (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/#covered-results); that way, MongoDB shouldn't have to scan the docs. Might require `hint()` and `find().count()` as projection.

Comment: @mnemosyn The point about doing `find({}, $projection).count()` was simply amazing. It's very strange mongodb doesn't understand itself that it can do a "covered index count" if what it's counting can be covered by an index, and we have to tell in manually to project the fields and then count! For me on a sharded cluster of 4 shards and 300,000,000 records, `col.count({is_active: true})` takes nearly a minute, but `col.find({}, {is_active: 1, _id: 0}).count({is_active: true})` takes less than 2 seconds!

Comment: But `cursor.count()` does not take a query parameter : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/ (unlike collection.count() : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

Comment: @sachav is right - the query is fast, because it's running a count on a full collection, without filtering.